# MySQL how to get correct count of all desired fields in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say i have a table:

ID, City1, City2, City3, Country, .... (not important)

The application asks people where would they like to live in let's say France.
So it is mandatory to add at least one city, but you can add 3 max cities.

So for instance we have in table data:

```
ID    City1    City2    City3    Country   UserID
--------------------------------------------------
1     Paris      /        /      France      1
2     Paris    Nice       /      France      2
3     Paris    Nice       /      France      3
4     Nice     Paris    Lyon     France      4
5     Lyon     Paris    Nice     France      5
6     Cannes   Nice     Paris    France      6
7     Paris    Cannes   Lyon     France      7
--------------------------------------------------
```

So now i display all users on a page when someone clicks France.
Then above users i want to display all cities with number like Paris(n) for
example.

so if i write:

```
    select City1 as city, count(1) as num 
    from table_c 
   where Country = "France" group by City1;
```

i get Paris(4), but i need to get Paris(7), because i want also display City2 and City3, I do not know how to write such an SQL statement.

I tried with many SQL statements, but then i get couple of times Paris(n) displayed, haw can this be done. If it can be?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. (Or use case expressions.)

Comment: how can this be done, i am not very experienced with SQL, is it possible you can write me an example please. Thank you

Comment: `SELECT city, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT country, city1 AS city FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT country, city2 FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT country, city3 FROM my_table) x GROUP BY city`. Note that enumerated columns (above 2, say) are often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: I will try now and get back to you all :)

Comment: Thank you everyone, that solved my problem. I checked all and are working perfectly for what i need. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this sql and let me know if this works

```
select city, count(1) as num from (
select City1 as city
from table_c
where Country = "France" and city1 is not null
UNION ALL
select City2 as city
from table_c
where Country = "France" and city2 is not null
UNION ALL
select City3 as city
from table_c
where Country = "France" and city3 is not null
) tbl
group by city
```

Comment: That's a copy of more then one answer here.

Comment: I just saw that there were more answers than mine

Answer (score 3):

In case `CITY1` column contain all of the cities, then you can simply do this:

```
SELECT t.city1,sum(t.city1 = t.city2 + t.city1 = t.city3 + t.city1 = t.city4) 
FROM table_c t
WHERE t.Country = "France"
GROUP BY t.city1
```

If not, use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT t.city,count(*) FROM (
    SELECT City1 as city FROM table_c WHERE Country = "France"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT City2 FROM table_c WHERE Country = "France"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT City3 FROM table_c WHERE Country = "France"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT City4 FROM table_c WHERE Country = "France") t
GROUP BY t.city
```

This will give you the correct results

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT      city,
            SUM(cnt) AS num
    FROM    (
        SELECT      City1 AS city,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM    table_c
            WHERE   Country = 'France'
        GROUP BY    City1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      City2 AS city,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM    table_c
            WHERE   Country = 'France'
        GROUP BY    City2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      City3 AS city,
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM    table_c
            WHERE   Country = 'France'
        GROUP BY    City3
        ) tmp
GROUP BY    tmp.city;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;)

```
select city, count(1)
from (
    select City1 as city
    from table_c 
    where Country = "France"
    union all 
    select City2 as city
    from table_c 
    where Country = "France"
    union all 
    select City3 as city
    from table_c 
    where Country = "France") tmp
group by city
```